# Why Formik handleBlur doesn't run two functions?

Tags: react-native, formik

After user types the name, I check for its uniqueness in handleBlur. The check runs fine, but the warnings from yup are not showing on blur. Thus `handleBlur('name')` is not running:

```js
// onBlur={handleBlur('name')} // This runs fine! 

 onBlur={async () => {
   const isUnique = await checkUserNameUniqueness(values.name);
         if (!isUnique) userNameIsNotUnique();
         handleBlur('name');
}}
```

I tried to run it without `sync/await` but nothing.
Is there a way to fix that?

As I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384089/how-to-call-two-function-in-onchange-using-formik) there is a way to run two functions in `onChange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
onEndEditing={handleBlur('name')}
onBlur={otherOnBlurFunction}
```

Comment: Hello @Ahmed, thanks for your effort. I tried your solution, and I got some errors from TypeScript. Nevertheless I kept on trying and I ended up with this solution: `onBlur={checkName.bind(null, values.name)}` Thanks